# Windows Phone 8.1 app manifest localization using resource from different assembly

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a windows phone 8.1 application (Universal app).
App has the following structure:

1. MyApp.Resources (separate assembly with resources)

   - Strings

     - en-US

       - Resources.resw
     - ru-RU

       - Resources.resw
2. MyApp.WindowsPhone (WP 8.1 universal app)

   - Package.appxmanifest
   - (... other stuff)

In Resources.resw I have a text with a key 'ApplicationTitle' and I want to use this text from Resource.resw file in Package.appxmanifest to localize application's 'Display Name'

When I use the following paths for 'Display Name' it doesn't work:

1. ms-resouces:MyApp.Resources\Resources\ApplicationTitle
2. ms-resouces:\MyApp.Resources\Resources\ApplicationTitle
3. ms-resouces:ApplicationTitle

Is it possible to use resources from referenced assembly to localize app package? If yes, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be "ms-resource" without the "s". [How to load string resources (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx#Loading_strings_from_the_Windows_Store_app_manifest.)

I am not sure if the 1 and 2 will work like that but 3 should work fine like this:

```
ms-resource:ApplicationTitle
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works and why the asker's attempts don't? It will make the answer more useful to those who come later.